# Can't get userContent.css to work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I'm using Firefox 48.0 on Ubuntu 14.

My profile directory is `~/.mozilla/firefox/v2fcrlqx.default`

I've put a file in there called `userContent.css` with a simple test rule in it:

```
body { background-color: red; }
```

But I'm not getting any results.

I also tried creating a folder called Chrome beneath my profile directory and copying `userContent.css` into that, but that doesn't work either.

Has Firefox dropped support for user stylesheets or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong but what is hard to say without seeing it **not** working.

Comment: BY "not working" I mean that when I browse to a test HTML page with no styles defined, I see the default browser styles for Firefox and not the rule from the user style sheet. What information would be useful to you to help debug this further ?

Comment: Fixed it now - see above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've fixed it. The user stylesheet has to go into a directory called `chrome` (not `Chrome`) below the profile directory.

Answer (score 22):

User styles are now disabled by default in Firefox.

To activate them:

- Type about:config?filter=toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets in the address bar. Set the option to true.
- Restart Firefox.

hope it will help.